# Are resource nodes (ore, wood, herbs) instanced?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Are resource nodes (e.g. ore veins, trees, bushes...) instanced?
I mean, does each player get his/her own set?
On other MMOs resources are first come first serve, and I am under the impression that in this game everyone can gather resources from the same source (i.e. eveyone gets their own instanced copy) but I am not sure, and I couldn't find it on the GW2 wiki.

Comment: It definitely seems that way from actual play and what I've observed, but I can't say for certain

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resources are instanced per player - my party and I harvest from the same nodes all the time.

Comment: However they disappear shortly after someone gathers them: I can gather from the same node as a random player who beat me to it, but if I wait a few seconds it expires before I can begin the process. So it's halfway individual.

Comment: That's never happened to us?

Comment: Well it disappears when the harvesting is done. It's happened to me that someone finishes harvesting a node before I've started, leaving it to disappear. I've only seen it once or twice though, so if you regularly have players lagging behind on the harvesting, you're probably correct and I'm wrong.

Comment: I've noticed the same behaviour for quest nodes (e.g. spike traps, worm holes, suspicious bushes... depending on the area). Several players can benefit from the same node, although some times they do disappear, so I'm not 100% sure

Comment: I experimented specifically with crafting nodes, they are fully instanced. Probably the behavior of quest nodes is what confused me in the first place.